# JTable and MySQL Issue

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am not sure why my code does not function well, it may be something rather easy to fix but I wanted to get input from the page, I get an error which says that the item selected cannot be cast to an object in this case the column selected

```
void delete() throws SQLException{
    int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (input == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        DVDItem user = (DVDItem)tableDVD.getModel().getValueAt(tableDVD.getSelectedRow(), tableDVD.getSelectedColumn());
        mc.deleteItem(user.getkey());
    }
    updateList();
}
```

how do I make it so it would convert it to the DVDItem object and then delete by accessing its key, thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that the column contains a value or property of `DVDItem`.  Instead, you should asking the model for the representation of the row and this will be determined by what type of table model you are using...

Comment: I dont quite understand, I mean logically it makes sense to pass in the whole values for the row to the object but how would I do that?

Comment: How did you construct the original table model?  By default, `TableModel` makes no assumptions about how a row is defined

Comment: this is my table declaration
 `tableDVD = new JTable();
  tableDVD.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
   new Object[][] {
   },
   new String[] {
    "KEY", "Title", "Director", "Genre", "Date"
   }
  ));`

Answer (score 2):

> I mean logically it makes sense to pass in the whole values for the row to the object but how would I do that?

The DefaultTableModel contains individual Objects for every column in a row. You can't just magically create a DVDItem. So the getValueAt() method will return the Object for the given row/column. The Object it is returns depends on the value you added to the model.

If you want to add DVDItem objects to the model then you need to create a custom model. Check out  [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/). You can either use the BeanTableModel as is or you can extend the `RowTableModel` by implementing a couple of methods. The choice is yours.

Comment: the class DVDItem consists of 4 strings and an int so each jtable column holds those values accordingly, I want to select a row and  get all those fields to make a DVDItem object which I can manipulate to update the database table, I am sorry if I am stubborn or not getting this info but I just need to pass the dvditem object into the other class to manipulate it, im probably confusing da hell out of everyone

Comment: So you either create an store a DVDItem object in the model. That is what the RowTableModel is designed for. Or you use the DefaultTableModel and store the data as separate field. Then when you want to create your DVDItem you need to invoke model.getValueAt(...) 5 times. One for each column in the selected row.

Comment: so DVDItem would be an array of the values in the row? I will give it a try thank you!!!

Comment: I invoked dvdItem's constructor and filled in each slot with the appropriate column, it works now, thanks!!